# Micrometer timed annotation on Kafka Listener

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-micrometer

I have Micrometer timed annotation on Kafka Listener for some reason I am not getting this metrics generated. I have other metrics for counters I could see them generated. Just wanted to double-check if @Timed annotation work for @KafkaListener ?

```
@Timed(value = "kafka.consumer.processing.time", percentiles = {0.75, 0.90, 0.95})
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.input.topic}", groupId = "${kafka.consumer.group.id}")
public void consumeFromInputTopic(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing I can think of that would prevent `@Timed` working with a `@KafkaListener` (but I have not tested it).

That said, since version 2.3, the container already maintains `Timer`s for listeners

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#micrometer

Comment: Thanks, We can use 2.3 Timer's for listeners.

Comment: I see the Timer but I don't get the buckets, only _sum _count_ and _max. I'm using Prometheus as a monitoring system.